# cordova wp8 web app: ajax callbacks not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, cordova

i am developing an app for windows phone 8, using phonegap for the app itself and asp.net web api for the server.

My current problem is, that no callbacks are executed when a normal ajax request comes back from the server (the request itself is successfull and returns json formatted data as it should)

javascript:

```
var req = $.ajax({  
    url: url,  
    type: "GET",  
    data: {  PhoneUuid: phoneUuid  }
})

req
.done(function (response) {
        alert(response);
        //stuff to do
})
.fail(function (req, statusText) {
        alert(statusText);
        //errors to display
});
```

as stated above, the request works fine (tested with windows phone 8 emulator and weinre remote debugger), but neither of the two callbacks are fired.

my question: is there something wrong with my code , or is windows phone just not executing callbacks on cross domain requests?

Comment: You must use `JSONP` for cross-domain AJAX requests. Start by specifying that in your `$.ajax` options: `{ dataType: 'jsonp' }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add url of website that you are ajaxing to, to your Access Element value in your `config.xml`.

```
<access origin="http://yourwebsite.com" subdomains="true" />
```